# Manter valor de variavel em uma função python

Tags: python

Dentro de uma função tenho uma variável acumulativa, e chamo essa função repetidas vezes, o problema que ela perde os valores a cada vez que entra. 
Resumindo o que eu quero fazer é:

```
def teste(a):
  a=a+1
  c=7
  print a
  return c


def main():   
 a=1
    for b in range(0,5):
        c=teste(a)
main()
```

a saída é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

gostaria de manter o valor de a, e a saída nesse caso ser incrementada.

Comment: Você está com dois `a`s no seu código: um é o parâmetro formal da função e o outro é a variável global.

Comment: esse é um código simples para reproduzir a ideia, no caso, se fosse global daria certo, pense que a segunda parte esta dentro de uma função

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python não tem um método de declarar variáveis estáticas, mas existem alguns meios e fazer isso.

```
def static_num(): # método com variável estática
    static_num.x += 1 # incremento
    return static_num.x

static_num.x = 0 # inicia variável

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(10):
        print static_num()
```

Answer (score 0):

Então o erro que deve, se deve pelo fato que você está apenas chamando a variavel que esta na função teste.Sem incrementar nenhum valor a ela, logo ela irá se repetir no lop for. Para resolver isso basta acrescentar a variavel b que está no seu for:

```
   def teste(a):
  a=a+1
  c=7
  print (a)
  return c


def main():   
    a=1
    for b in range(0,5):
        c=teste(a+b)
main()
```

Assim ele vai incrementar com a variavel sem mutalá diretamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]